# The best and fastest way to switch elements style in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Adding `currentSelected` class when I click the item, and removing the previously-selected item's `currentSelected` class if I select another item. And remove `currentSelected` class when I click outside of the item list.

```
<ul>
    <li class="dataItem currentSelected">item 1</li>
    <li class="dataItem"> item 2</li>
    <li class="dataItem"> item 3</li>
    <li class="dataItem"> item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul id="myul">
    <li class="dataItem currentSelected">item 1</li>
    <li class="dataItem"> item 2</li>
    <li class="dataItem"> item 3</li>
    <li class="dataItem"> item 4</li>
</ul>
```

.

```
$('#myul li.dataItem').click(function(e){
   $(this).addClass('currentSelected')
   .siblings('.currentSelected')
   .removeClass('currentSelected');
   e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(){
   $('.currentSelected')
       .removeClass('currentSelected');
});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/jHSC5/)

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to handle everything at the document level, so that the logic of adding and removing classes can be combined into one handler, and there's no need to unecessarily block event propagation.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    $('li.dataItem').removeClass('currentSelected');
    $(e.target).closest('li.dataItem').addClass('currentSelected');
});
```

If the click didn't come from an `li.dataItem`, then `$(e.target).closest('li.dataItem')` will return an empty jQuery object, and `addClass` will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $('.currentSelected').removeClass('currentSelected');
    $(this).addClass('currentSelected');
};
```

What you can do, is store a variable which will hold the last item selected, so you can slip the first css-class selector.

```
var lastItem;

$('li').click(function(){
    if(lastItem) {
        lastItem.removeClass('currentSelected');
    }
    lastItem = $(this).addClass('currentSelected');
};
```